# Play Framework config value in view

Tags: playframework

How can I access the value `application.name` from `conf/application.conf` in a view?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Play! 2.0 configuration variables in application.conf?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857907/access-play-2-0-configuration-variables-in-application-conf)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use following code sample to do so:

```
${play.configuration['application.name']}
```

Also see http://groups.google.com/group/play-framework/browse_thread/thread/1412ca8fc3edd22f

Comment: For the record: things changed with Play 2.0, this is not going to work anymore. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857907/access-play-2-0-configuration-variables-in-application-conf for a Play 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 7):

Update for Play 2.5.x

In Play Scala 2.5.x, method current in object Play is deprecated. In order to read a value from conf/application.conf, you have to use DI instead.

Inject `play.api.Configuration` in your controller :

`class MyController @Inject() (val configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller`

Then, you can directly use `configuration` in your methods :

```
def sayMyName = Action { request =>
   Ok("Your name is " + configuration.getString("application.name"))
}
```

You can also use `configuration` in your view Twirl template :

```
def sayMyNameUsingView = Action { request =>
   implicit lazy val config = configuration
   Ok(views.html.index())
}
```

Send the injected `configuration` as implicit to the given `index.scala.html`

```
@()(implicit val configuration:play.api.Configuration)
<html>
  <body>
    <h1>Your name is @configuration.getString("application.name")</h1> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for Play 2...

In Play Scala 2.3.x, to read a value from `conf/application.conf`, you can do the following:

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
current.configuration.getString("application.name")
```