# Access Play! 2.0 configuration variables in application.conf?

Tags: playframework-2.0

Previously in Play! v1 it was really easy to define configuration variables in `application.conf` and then access them like so:

```
play.configuration("db.driver")
```

However now I can't find anything in the documentation for similar uses in v2 or a proper alternative. What's the method for doing so?

Comment: For new visitors, this question is not limited to Play 2.0. Multiple other answers have been made for other play versions below.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

As of Play 2.5, `play.api.Play.current` is deprecated. You should use dependency injection to inject the `Environment` or `Configuration` and use that to read the configuration value:

```
class HomeController @Inject() (configuration: play.api.Configuration) extends Controller {
  def config = Action {
    Ok(configuration.underlying.getString("db.driver"))
  }
}
```

Checkout the [Play documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Deprecated-play.Play-and-play.api.Play-methods) for more detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you for providing an updated answer. I will be marking this as the correct answer for future users of Play! 2.x

Comment: Thanks, this should work great until Play is changed again.

Comment: So how to make this work in a test class? E.g. Spces2?

Answer (score 115):

The Play 2.0 Scala equivalent to this would be:

```
Play.current.configuration.getString("db.driver")
```

You will also need `import play.api.Play`

The full docs for this are [here](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/api/2.0/scala/play/api/Configuration.html).

Comment: many thanks and I appreciate the link. hopefully we see more docs in the Scala home outside the API explorer :)

Comment: Note that depending on the case you couldn't make the assumption that the application has not yet started or you didn't need the application 'till this portion of code; you might use `play.api.Play.maybeApplication.map(_.configuration.getString("db.driver"))`

Comment: This is now deprecated in Play 2.5. See the [migration guide](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Migration25#Deprecated-play.Play-and-play.api.Play-methods)

Answer (score 57):

Applies to Play 2.0 - In **Java Controller** you can use following:

```java
String optionValue = Play.application().configuration().getString("db.driver");
```

To get variable **in view** use this:

```scala
@play.Play.application().configuration().getString("db.driver")
```

Comment: How can I use it into the javascript?

Comment: @premraj Use share it as an HTML5 data attribute of an invisible div.

Answer (score 24):

In **Play 2.3.2 for Java** you can use the `com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory` option:

```
Config conf = ConfigFactory.load();
String myFooBarConfiguration = conf.getString("foo.bar");
```

Fast moving API!

Comment: This is the correct answer for the current version of Play... without the use of DI.

Comment: This solution is independent from Play version. It also works in Scala. Could be dependent on HOCON version if they ever were to change that access point.

Answer (score 6):

Another method tested in **Play 2.3[.8] / Java** to access values from application.conf:

To check the Play version, examine the file project/plugins. The line that contains "sbt-plugin" should have a version specification like "2.3.8".

If, for example, application.conf contains the lines

```
myConfigStringValue=abc
myConfigBooleanValue=true
```

one could query that values from a java file/class like

```
import play.Configuration;
...
String myString = Configuration.root().getString("myConfigStringValue");
Boolean myBoolean = Configuration.root().getBoolean("myConfigBooleanValue");
```

The get... methods return null if the value is not found, there are also get... methods that take a default value as argument.

For details see
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/java/index.html

and inspect class play.Configuration.

Answer (score 5):

In Play Scala 2.3.x and 2.4.x, to read a value from `conf/application.conf`, you can do the following:

```
import play.api.Play.current
...
current.configuration.getString("db.driver")
```

Answer (score 5):

In Java with play > 2.5.X you can read the configuration values via the ConfigFactory helper:

```
ConfigFactory.load().getString("redis.url")
```

or

```
ConfigFactory.load().getInt("redis.port")
```

The object **Config** will convert the param into the correct type. It exposes the methods to handle any java type (getDouble, getLong, etc, etc)

Doc: 
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.0/api/java/play/Configuration.html

Comment: This worked fine for me on Scala with Play 2.8.19 as of Feb 2023.

Answer (score 4):

In Play 2.0.1 Java, you need to do this:

```
import play.Application.*;
...
String optionValue = play.Play.application().configuration().getString("my.config");
```

Answer (score 3):

In Play 2.1 ,Scala
Firstly you have to `import play.api.Play
Play.current.configuration.getString("varibale name")`

Answer (score 2):

In case you are using **Play Scala**, i found this approach the most appropriate after searching for some best practices. To do so, i injected the configuration and then accessed my config key like this:

```
import play.api.Configuration

class myClass @Inject()(
  config: Configuration
) {
  val configValue: String = config.underlying.getString("configKey")
}
```

This way, you do not get the Option, but the String. In case it is not available, it throws an exception:

```
Error injecting constructor, com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'configKey'
```

Main goal was to avoid the pure `get` solution that [@peoplemerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857907/access-play-2-0-configuration-variables-in-application-conf/26430811#26430811) already mentioned while throwing a specific exception if None.

Answer (score 2):

As a small contribution/improvement to all the `@Inject` answers here, you don't need to call the `config.underlying` implementation. You can directly use `config.getString`

example:

```
@Singleton
class RESTSessionChecker @Inject()(
    implicit override val conf: Configuration)
    extends Filter {

   val MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = conf.getString("MAX_CONCURRENT_REQUESTS").
         getOrElse("100").toInt
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to access configurations in Play using Scala

The following works on Play 2.7.x

**Option 1: With DI**

```
import play.api.Configuration
.... other imports ...

class MyActor @Inject()(config: Configuration) extends Actor  {
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher"))
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher")) // w/o optional
 println(config.getOptional[Int]("value_1").getOrElse(2))    // with optional 
 .....
 }
```

**Option 2: w/o DI**

```
import play.api.Configuration
.... other imports ...

class MyActor() extends Actor {
 val config = new Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf")) // application.conf is optional 
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher"))
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher")) // w/o optional
 println(config.getOptional[Int]("value_1").getOrElse(2))    // with optional 
 .....
 }
```

Comment: How to `@Inject()` in a test class?

Comment: @rapt I would suggest taking a look at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaFunctionalTestingWithScalaTest.


Basically, you'll need to override the Play application that is used during a test. When you do this, the `GuiceApplicationBuilder` gives you a chance to override default bindings. Other than that, your existing Play components will be instantiated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you need to import play.api.Play.current.  Then if you run:

```
current.configuration.getString("db.driver")
```

On 2.3.x / scala 10 you'll get

```
type mismatch; 
found   : Option[String]
required: String
```

If this is mandatory, this will work:

```
url = current.configuration.getString("db.driver").get
```

Anyone suggest a better answer?

Answer (score 0):

// new approach post 2.5.x

```
    import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.Configuration

class Example @Inject() (playconfiguration: Configuration) {
    def index() = {
        val confString: String = playconfiguration.getString("confKey").get
    }
```

}

source :
https://www.webkj.com/play-framework/play-scala-2.5-reading-config-using-di