# How to use SORM framework with Play Framework?

Tags: scala, orm, playframework, sorm

I find [SORM](http://sorm-framework.org/) very Interesting and promising but I cant find a way to Integrate It with play any guides?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Install Play >= 2.1.0.
2. Generate a project using Play's guides
3. Add appropriate SORM's and chosen database's dependencies to the generated `project/Build.scala`, e.g.:

   ```
   val appDependencies = Seq(
     "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8",
     "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168"
   )
   ```
4. In the same file make sure that your project depends on the same Scala version, on which SORM depends (for SORM 0.3.8 it's Scala 2.10.1):

   ```
   val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
     scalaVersion := "2.10.1"
   )
   ```

   *If you miss that step, you may bump into [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16925870/485115).*
5. In `app/models/package.scala` place all your case classes and SORM's instance declaration, e.g.:

   ```
   package models

   case class A( name : String )
   case class B( name : String )

   import sorm._
   object Db extends Instance(
     entities = Set(Entity[A](), Entity[B]()),
     url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test"
   )
   ```

   *Note that there is no requirement to follow these naming and location conventions - e.g., you can put your SORM instances in your controllers or elsewhere if you want.*
6. In `app/controllers/Application.scala` place some controller actions utilizing SORM, e.g.:

   ```
   package controllers

   import play.api.mvc._
   import models._

   object Application extends Controller {

     def index = Action {
       val user = Db.save(A("test"))
       Ok(user.id.toString)
     }

   }
   ```

   This will print out a generated id of the saved `A` case class value.
7. Run your server using `play run` or `play start` command.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea how to easily grab the db.default settings from Play?

Comment: In case anyone needs it, this answer explains it well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9857907/access-play-2-0-configuration-variables-in-application-conf

Answer (score 2):

Play was updated to use a new build file format

Ref : [Build.scala is not created in play](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946539/build-scala-is-not-created-in-play)

You can continue from build.sbt file anymore

ForEx:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  cache,
  "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8",
  ws,
  specs2 % Test
)
```

For new usage :

[Using SORM with Play Framework 2.3.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28759698/using-sorm-with-play-framework-2-3-8)

Answer (score 0):

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
jdbc,
cache,
ws,
"org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.22",
"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168",
"org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "1.5.1" % Test
)
```

Comment: When giving an answer it is preferable to give [some explanation as to WHY your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) is the one.  This is especially true on *very* old questions