# SORM development plans

Tags: scala, orm, sorm

Does anyone know which latest scala version SORM supports? Also is the development of SORM ongoing? Finally, Are there any plans to support noSQL databases or as the name implies, is it only for relational databases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SORM supports the whole 2.10.* Scala branch.

Development is ongoing but isn't very fast. With the release of version 0.4 SORM will be hugely refactored and modularized towards much easier third-party driver development. I expect this to draw in a more substantial contribution to the project.

SORM's APIs are getting changed to get free from chains of relational drivers and to generalize with future NoSQL drivers implementations in mind. Though I must admit that no specific implementations of NoSQL drivers are planned for the 0.4.0 release, but it's planned to work on a CouchDB support after this release.

Yeah, with these plans the framework's title seems to become quite confusing, but it's the issue with the least priority right now.

Comment: Thanks. When do you expect to release 0.4 version?

Comment: @SriniK It's hard to tell. The amount of work is huge: the framework is being almost completely rewritten from ground up. I'm tempted to say that it'll be a couple of months, but it can be more, so I can't make any promises.

Comment: Ok. Do you need any collaborators on this? I can help, at least with unit tests before getting more involved, if you like.

Comment: @SriniK We can discuss this by email. My address should be available either here or on github