# Using SORM with Play Framework causes reflection exceptions to be thrown

Tags: scala, reflection, playframework, sorm

I've been trying to get SORM working with Play Framework 2.2-SNAPSHOT as well as 2.1.1. Currently I'm trying to run a minimalistic sample application that I created in order to track down the issue more easily. Unfortunately the error message I receive doesn't help me at all.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8",
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168"
)
```

---

```
# Database configuration
#
db.default.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:play"
# db.default.user=sa
# db.default.password=""
```

---

```
case class Car( brand: String, wheels: Int )

object Db extends Instance( Seq( Entity[Car]() ), "jdbc:h2:mem:play" )
```

---

```
object Application extends Controller {
  def index = Action {
    Db.query[Car].count()
    Ok("hello wolrd")
  }
}
```

Results in this stacktrace:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo.firstArgument(Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:326) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$17$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:324) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.libs.concurrent.PlayPromise$$anonfun$extend1$1.apply(Promise.scala:113) [play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo.firstArgument(Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;
    at play.api.mvc.ActionBuilder$$anon$1.apply(Action.scala:222) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(Action.scala:109) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.utils.Threads$.withContextClassLoader(Threads.scala:18) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:108) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.mvc.Action$$anonfun$apply$1$$anonfun$apply$2$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(Action.scala:106) ~[play_2.10.jar:2.1.1]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.reflect.internal.TreeInfo.firstArgument(Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;)Lscala/reflect/internal/Trees$Tree;
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Typers$Typer.parentTypes(Typers.scala:1550) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.templateSig(Namers.scala:861) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.getSig$1(Namers.scala:1300) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer.typeSig(Namers.scala:1347) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Namers.scala:709) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
    at scala.tools.nsc.typechecker.Namers$Namer$$anonfun$monoTypeCompleter$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(Namers.scala:708) ~[scala-compiler.jar:na]
```

Comment: Looks like a binary compatibility issue.

Comment: I confirm the issue. Getting to fix it.

Comment: What a beautiful thing to hear after hours of frustrating trial and error. Thank you for taking care of the issue (:

Comment: Opened [a ticket](https://github.com/sorm/sorm/issues/17). In the mean time please try a previous version `"com.github.nikita-volkov" % "sorm" % "0.3.7"` (note the different artifact group) and report back. It should be working fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay. It's not a bug. **SORM 0.3.8** depends on **Scala 2.10.1** and **Play 2.1.x** uses **Scala 2.10.0**. The exceptions you get are caused by **Play** mixing artifacts from both **Scala** versions.

To fix this issue all you need to do is just tell **Play** to use a proper **Scala** version by adding `scalaVersion := "2.10.1"` to project settings in a file *project/Build.scala*.

The final build script may look like this:

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

  val appName         = "play-test"
  val appVersion      = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.8",
    "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.3.168"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
    resolvers += 
      "Local Maven Repository" at 
      "file:///"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository",
    scalaVersion := "2.10.1" // <--- ! This is the fix !
  )

}
```

Comment: 2.10.1 is supposed to be a drop-in replacement for 2.10.0. Could you please elaborate on what exactly causes an exception? upd. Okay, nevermind, I understand now.

Comment: @EugeneBurmako It was really more of a guess. After giving it more thought, I now believe it may be caused by Play probably having no dependencies on __scala-reflect__ or __scala-compiler__, which SORM currently does have both, so it may turn out that Play mixes __scala-library-2.10.0__ with __scala-reflect-2.10.1__, or something like that. What do you think?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm still getting a RuntimeException when trying to ```fetch``` an element. ```ClassCastException: __wrapper$1$8dcf00bfeb4549a397715a02daf05008.__wrapper$1$8dcf00bfeb4549a397715a02daf05008$PersistedAnonymous10$1 cannot be cast to [my class]```. Saving items or counting for instance is working now however.

Comment: @Taig Fetching works fine on my end. Probably there is a mistake in your code. You can ask a new question.

Comment: @NikitaVolkov Where does the stack trace come from? Is it from the runtime compilation performed by Sorm?

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right, it's working. There must be some misconfiguration in my main project. Thanks for your help! (:

Comment: @EugeneBurmako I don't know. I don't know what caused it. Taig says it was just his misconfiguration, so whatever.

Comment: same thing happen when using sorm 0.3.12 with scala 2.10.1 / using scala 2.10.3 with sorm 0.3.12 fixes the bug