# Build.scala is not created in play

Tags: playframework-2.0

I'm trying to learn play, doing the tutorial in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaTodoList

The problem I have is the the file project/Build.scala is not created for me. Should I create it manually?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We updated Play to use a new build file format, but we missed that piece of code in the documentation.  If you go to that page now, you should find it has the correct code.

To answer your question, you need to add the postgresql dependency by updating `build.sbt` with the following:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  "postgresql" % "postgresql" % "8.4-702.jdbc4"
)
```

Comment: Hi James, Just downloaded play-2.2.0.zip on Oct 17 and the local version of the documentation still references Build.scala.  (i.e. the tutorial at http://localhost:9000/@documentation/ScalaTodoList)

Comment: Same for me, I want to have Build.scala class generated, but "play new" command does not creates it as supposed. When I am trying to create it manually and remove build.sbt, play command cannot resolve PlayProject as it referenced here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Build