# Installing Play Salat in Intellij IDEA project

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, mongoose, salat

I'm writing a simple application on Scala using Play Framework and I'd like to use [Play Salat](https://github.com/leon/play-salat) in my application. I'm using Intellij IDEA Ultimate as the IDE and I've generated the Play project as it's said in the [IDEA documentation](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IntelliJIDEA/Play+Framework+2.0). However, I'm unable to find the file 'project/Build.scala' which I have to modify according to the Play Salat installation guide. I've tried to create this file but I was unable to import the play.Project.

Here's what my project structure looks like:
[image: project structure screen]

I've tried to find any information as to how to install Salat but I haven't found anything which would help me.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions of Play Framework Build.scala is equivalent to built.sbt. You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946539/build-scala-is-not-created-in-play)

Comment: Thanks. I've already tried using Build.sbt to add library dependencies. However, I don't know what to do with 'val main = PlayProject' part of the Salat instruction. Where should I insert it? I suppose, the configuration part should go to conf/application.conf