# How to start a TCP Server within an PlayFramework (scala)

Tags: scala, tcp, playframework, h2, sorm

I am trying to share an in-memory H2 Database I created using SORM framework in my Play Framework application. Below is the code for my database code

```
object DB extends Instance(entities = Seq(Entity[Person]()), url ="jdbc:h2:mem:db1"){}
```

The solution stated at H2 Database site is to start a TCP Server. In Java applications I am able to share the database using the following code

```
org.h2.tools.Server server = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer();
server.start();

Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:mem:db1");
```

How can I start a tcp server in my Play application when it starts or when it is running?

Comment: I don't think you should run it as standalone server. play support running h2 out of the box. See [How to use SORM framework with Play Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908054/how-to-use-sorm-framework-with-play-framework)

Comment: I'm just resorting to this to create a quick prototype. thanks for the info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [playframework](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaGlobal) documentation, you should be able to place the code in onStart function.