# Using SORM with Play Framework 2.3.8

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, sorm

I am going through the [Video introduction to Play Framework](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eNCerkVyQdc) and, but I am stuck creating a DB object with SORM because the import fails.

I tried to add the dependencies in `plugins.sbt`, and relaunched activator, but it seems that activator cannot find the dependencies and I get and I get an `unresolved error`:

```
addSbtPlugin("org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.14")
addSbtPlugin("com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.181")
```

I got the versions from the [`Yvis` repository](http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/webapp/search/artifact/?5&q=sorm). I also tried other versions with no better luck.

Comment: should be add as libraryDependencies += "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.16"  in `build.sbt`,  but not an sbt plugin

Comment: Thanks! Eclipse was having troubles to recognize the import and that was confusing me even more, but now it works.

If you convert your comment into an answer, I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

should be add as

```
libraryDependencies += "org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.16"
```

in `build.sbt`,

but not as

```
addSbtPlugin("org.sorm-framework" % "sorm" % "0.3.14")
```

in `project/plugins.sbt`

Answer (score 3):

good answer by jilen; also, it can be a good idea to re-run sbt after changing the build.sbt, e.g. (in project root dir):

```
$ sbt
....
$ compile
...
$ eclipse
```

(the last two apply to Eclipse users more - and then restart Eclipse to make sure the changes are picked up (Refresh/Clean may not be enough)).

Comment: Re-running SBT fixed my issue. Thanks.