# how to read a list of objects from the configuration file in play framework

Tags: java, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

How can i read a list of users from the configuration file in play framework? 
i have tried doing something like this:

```
users=[{uid:123,pwd:xyz},{uid:321,pwd:abc}]
```

from the play application

```
 List<Object> uids = Play.application().configuration().getList("users");
```

will give me this a list of objects, if I iterate through the list i get each object as

```
{uid=123,pwd=xyz} and {uid=321,pwd=abc}
```

at this point i don't know how i can elegantly get the value of the uid, i can do some hacky job as omit the first and last bracket and parse for the before after equal sign, but it would be too ugly! any idea? (the application is written in java)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I had recently the same problem and this is still unanswered,
here is my suggestion:

```
List<User> users = getConfig().getConfigList("users").stream().map(
            config -> new User(config.getString("uid"), config.getBoolean("pwd"))
    ).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

As far as I know there are no tuples or anything in Java, you need to use either an object or a list with two elements. I decided to go for an object here, you can also return a list.

Answer (score 4):

A Scala implementation that avoids the deprecated `getConfigList` method would rely on retrieving a `Seq[Configuration]` as follows:

```
  case class UserConfig(uid: Int, pwd: String)
  val userConfigs: Seq[UserConfig] = configuration.get[Seq[Configuration]]("users").map { userConfig =>
    UserConfig(userConfig.get[Int]("uid"), userConfig.get[String]("pwd"))
  }
```

Comment: what is the value of `configuration` in `configuration.get`?

Comment: I got my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37099936/4621188) It is through dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

*A list of uid's sounds to me like:*

```
# List of UID's
users=[123,456,789] // every number represents a UID
```

Then you can get this list as:

```
List<Object> uids = Play.application().configuration().getList("users");
```

And then do what you want with this:

```
for (Iterator<Object> iterator = uids.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {        
    Object object = (Object) iterator.next();
    System.out.println(object);
}
```

Is this what you are looking for?
BTW, you can read more about Play Framework configuration options: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/Configuration

Comment: No, that was a simplified example, i need to pass more information regarding each user, imagine i need to pass uid and password!

Comment: and the documentation does not explain how you can read json objects from the config file