# Using application.conf properties in views Play Scala

Tags: html, scala, playframework

I have a link to open a website in one of the views in my application and I need for that website to be dependant on a site set in application.conf.

View now:

class="nav-link" href="https://my.website.com" target="_blank">

This doesn't work:

class="nav-link" href=current.configuration.getString("client.server.url") target="_blank">

application.conf:

client.server.url = "https://my.website.com"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this Play Framework - Twirl Templates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7716948/play-framework-config-value-in-view

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Configuration inside a Play Template you need to inyect it into the Controller and then give it to the view though its constructor.

```
@Singleton
class FooController @Inject()(config:Configuration, cc: ControllerComponents) extends AbstractController(cc) {

  def bar = Action {
    Ok(views.html.baz(config))
  }

}
```

then your view baz.scala.html

```
@(config:play.api.Configuration)

<a class="nav-link" href="@config.getString("client.server.url")" target="_blank">LINK</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help can't resolve an error on: Ok(views.html.baz(config)) Getting a type mismatch on config. "Expected: String got actual: Configuration.

Comment: Play Version 2.6.1

Comment: and your view has a parameter like this? `@(config:play.api.Configuration)`
I have a project here with scala 2.12.6 and Play 2.6 with that code compiling.

Answer (score 0):

I use e.g. `@{play.Play.application.configuration.getString("play.http.context")}` but it might be deprecated in version 2.6. Just exchange `play.http.context` with your config parameter.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to access configurations in Play using Scala

The following works on Play 2.7.x

**Option 1: With DI**

```
import play.api.Configuration
.... other imports ...

class MyActor @Inject()(config: Configuration) extends Actor  {
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher"))
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher")) // w/o optional
 println(config.getOptional[Int]("value_1").getOrElse(2))    // with optional 
 .....
 }
```

**Option 2: w/o DI**

```
import play.api.Configuration
.... other imports ...

class MyActor() extends Actor {
 val config = new Configuration(ConfigFactory.load("application.conf"))
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher"))
 println(config.get[String]("akka_actor_custom_dispatcher")) // w/o optional
 println(config.getOptional[Int]("value_1").getOrElse(2))    // with optional 
 .....
 }
```